# django POST Method in Singup returning Internal Server 500 error

Tags: django, database, api, internal-server-error, http-status-code-500

I have this error when I want to signup in django the user will be create in database but it gives me this error and the response will not return can someone help me

[image: this is my models.py]
[image: this is my serializer.py]

[image: this is my view.py]

I want to get help and I want my quetion to be useful for others

Comment: First go to the console where you ran `./manage.py runserver` andread the error message. This will give you a good idea of where to look for the problem. If you still need help, please post your code and the full error message here as text, not screenshots. Screenshots are limited. For example, more than half of your screenshots are `import`s which are most likely not the cause of the problem. Please [edit] your question to include the code as text.

Comment: I check my console it gives me this error ( "token": Token.object.get(user=user).key,
AttributeError: type object 'Token' has no attribute 'object') and I checked my setting.py and also I added (rest_framework.auth token)

Comment: Yes it should be `objects` or `_default_manager` not `object`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question as I described in my first message.